# Finding power of exponent without known base in python

Tags: math, sympy

From an exponent x<sup>a</sup>, I am trying to get 'a' without a known value of 'x' using logarithm law log<sub>x</sub>(x<sup>a</sup>) = a

Originally I tried:

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
print(log(x,x))
```

Which returns 1 as expected. But when raised to any other power, does not give single value e.g.

```
print(log(x**2,x))
```

Which returns:

```
log(x**2)/log(x)
```

instead of 2.

Is there any alternative way to get the exponent or fix to my original code?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `expand` it will give you the result you are looking for. In addition, you can just get the exponent directly:

```
>>> log(x**2,x).expand()  # or expand_log(log(x**2,x))
2
>>> (x**2).exp
2
>>> (x**2).as_base_exp()[1]  # works for x**1, too, which is not a Pow
```

Comment: Maybe `.as_base_exp()` is best to handle the exponent 1 case.